# Error: Illegal frame index as variable value in WebStorm debugger

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, webstorm

While debugging with WebStorm 2016.2.3 a tiny toy Meteor 1.4.1.1 app written in CoffeeScript 1.2.4_1, some variables that I watch at breakpoints have value: `Error: Illegal frame index`.

Surprisingly, googling "Error: Illegal frame index" did not return any definition or explanation of what "illegal frame index" means, only some big uncommented code files.

Has anyone encountered this and figured out what it means?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with WebStorm and Meteor, I don`t know why it happens but in my case I have solved it through next workaround:

1. In Debug Tool Window tab, in Frames pane, click another frame
2. Click again on the current frame, wait for the data to be collected

I hope this helps you.